# sed to edit (not just print) lines of 65 characters

Tags: sed

It's easy to find instructions on how to print lines with 65 characters or more (Google "sed one-liners), but I can't figure out the syntax to actually *edit* a line (i.e., do a substitution) on such a line.

Comment: an example would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make changes on the lines which has 65 or above characters.

```
sed '/^.\{65,\}/s/.*/llll/' file
```

This would replace all the characters on the lines which has 65 or above characters to `llll`. Substitution works on those lines only.

`^.\{65,\}` search pattern which matches only those lines which satisfies the given condition. `\{65,\}` called repetition quantifier which repeats the previous token (that is `.`) 65 or more times. To save the changes made, you need to add inline edit `-i` parameter to your sed command.

Comment: Yours looks slightly simpler than mine (below). I'll use that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was able to piece it together. All I wanted to do was to replace "foo" with "bar," but only if the line has 65 characters or more. Turns out it looks like this:

```
sed '/\(^.\{65\}\)/s/foo/bar/' num.tmp
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj The `,` is not required; `.\{65\}` will match on every line which has at least 65 characters.

Comment: yep, beacuse we didn't use end `$` anchor, `,` in the regex is not required.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed 's/./&/65;T;s/pattern/replacement/' file
```

Replace character 65 by itself and if the substitution fails bail out otherwise ...

Answer (score -1):

I think you need the `-i` option.

```
$ man sed
```

Output:
...

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

Comment: Tangential at best; this does not answer the OP's actual question.